# Добавление записи в таблицу только если ячейки с таким значением еще нет в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

мне нужно составить таблицу с заказчикаи по IP
и проверять есть ли уже в таблице такой IP
Если есть то ничего не делать если нет то добавить вместо 4 должен быть айпи
4 вставлена для проверки

```
if(mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM checkout WHERE userip = '4'")or die ("Нdspafjael"))
{

mysqli_close($connection);
}
else{

mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM checkout")or die ("Невозможно  MySQL");
mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO checkout (userip) VALUES ('4')")or die ("Невозможно  к MySQL");
mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Comment: Сделайте поле userip уникальным и используйте `insert ... on duplicate key update userip=userip`. никаких проверок не надо

Comment: его надо в настройкаъ делать уникальным?
просто ip сам по себе уникален

Comment: Да, сделать на него уникальный индекс (`create unique index ...`). Структура БД должна полностью отражать реальный мир, если что то должно быть уникально это должно быть описано в структуре БД

Comment: *Если есть то ничего не делать* вряд ли это правильно... операторы - они тупые - будут десять раз пытаться ввести, и орать, что программа глючная. А если всё же ничего не делать, и создадите уникальный индекс - то ODKU не нужен, делайте просто `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: А что мешает проверить перед вставкой? Сделать SELECT перед вставкой на проверку, если запись есть, то вывести сообщение что уже есть, если нет то вставить.